# PRISMA.IO - Erasing data when migrate prod database

Tags: node.js, npm, prisma

I'm pretty sure the answer will be easy :) but I can't find any solution (official doc or googling).
I'm currently using Prisma with a sqlite database. Each time I run the command "npx prisma db push" all my data are erased. And I can't find a solution to migrate my production database without resetting the data ?
Do I need to script a dump or something like that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`db push` works well if:

You want to quickly prototype and iterate on schema design locally without the need to deploy these changes to other environments such as other developers, or staging and production environments.

In a development environment, use the migrate dev command to generate and apply migrations:

`npx prisma migrate dev`

In production and testing environments, use the migrate deploy command to apply migrations:

`npx prisma migrate deploy`

For more information, please check the Prisma [docs on migrations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate)